# Understand what really happens when calling a throwing function in a noexcept function

Tags: c++, gcc, terminate, noexcept

See the following code containing 3 implementations of a function calling another throwing function.

```
# include <stdexcept>

void f()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("");
}

void g1()
{
    f();
}

void g2() noexcept
{
    f();
}

void g3() noexcept
{
    try{ f(); } catch(...){ std::terminate(); }
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding of the `noexcept` specification, `g2` and `g3` are strictly equivalent. But, when I compile it in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KdsvGKKW9) with GCC, the generated code is strictly equivalent for `g1` and `g2`, but not for `g3`:

```
g1():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    f()
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
g2():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    f()
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
g3():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    f()
        jmp     .L9
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __cxa_begin_catch
        call    std::terminate()
.L9:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

**Why ?**

Comment: `g3()` catches the exception, and handles it by calling `std::terminate()`.  `g2()` causes the `__cxa_throw` to call `std::terminate()`.  Compiler Explorer filters out all the prologue and epilogue code that provides the stack unwinder with the function metadata that informs the unwinder how to propagate exceptions.  (That's the 5543 lines filtered, mentioned at the bottom.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: then, if I well understand, the difference between `g1` and `g2` is in the way it will be called ?

Comment: `g3()` is not throwing an exception. Internally throwing and immediately catching it is (when viewed from outside) like not throwing an exception. `g1` and `g2` let the exception escape from the function. What else did you expect to see in the output and why?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai : actually, I expected to see the same code generated for `g2` and `g3`. I understand now that the difference is in "how the function is called" and not "how the function is written".

Comment: hm not sure if I understand. It does not matter how you call `g2` or `g3`. `g2` does throw an exception (even though it is declared as `noexcept`). `g3` does not throw an exception

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai when I said "how the function is called", I think "how the function is called in the executable generated by the compiler".

Comment: The natural expectation, here, is that `g2` will internally generate the same code as `g3`. Something, somewhere, must be responsible for calling terminate() if something inside `g2` throws an exception. Where is that code?

Comment: *how the function is called*  The functions are all called the same way.

Comment: The `noexcept` specification is not for the benefit of code that is generated for the function, but is for the benefit of the caller: it is not necessary to generate unwinding information around the function call, because no exception can escape from the called function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way exceptions are implemented in GCC, there is no need to emit extra code for `noexcept` and `throws` checks. The compiler creates several tables with information about all functions, their stack variables and exceptions they are allowed to throw. When an exception is thrown, this info is used to unwind the call stack. It is during the stack unwinding the standard library will notice that there is a `noexcept` entry in the stack and call `std::terminate`. So *there is* a difference between `g1` and `g2`, but it's *not* in the `.text` section of the generated binary, but somewhere in [`.eh_frame`](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/460), [`eh_frame_hdr`](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/462) or [`.gcc_except_table`](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/464). These are not shown by godbolt.org.

If you execute these functions wrapped in `try-catch` from `main`, you will observe that indeed, despite the code of `g2` not having anything extra compared to `g1`, the execution will not reach the catch clause in `main` and `std::terminate` earlier. Roughly speaking, this `std::terminate` will happen when executing `throw` in `f`.

As for why `g3` code is different, it's probably because the optimizer couldn't look through all this involved exception handling logic and therefore didn't change the initially generated code much.

**EDIT**: Actually godbolt.org can display related ASM directives that populate the tables if you disable the filter for directives.

```
g1():
.LFB1414:
        .loc 1 9 1 is_stmt 1
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        .loc 1 10 6
        call    f()
        .loc 1 11 1
        nop
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

vs

```
g2():
.LFB1415:
        .loc 1 14 1
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA1415
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        .loc 1 15 6
        call    f()
        .loc 1 16 1
        nop
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Notice the extra lines

```
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA1415
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference if and only if the function actually needs to do something, either to catch the exception or to call a destructor, when an execption is thrown.

https://godbolt.org/z/PrqEeKrqP

Here's an example.

If every function **called** in a block is marked as `noexcept`, or if the **calling** function itself is `noexcept`, the compiler can safely omit all exception handling logic. Otherwise, a hidden `catch` block is generated to call destructors.

Note that I compile the example code with `-shared` flag to avoid inlining.

Answer (score -8):

Reading the noexcept reference on cppreference.com I came to the conclusion that the compiled code is not affects by `noexcept`

It is only a compile time evaluation and therefore does not influence the output of the compiler if just used on its own.

Comment: Very wrong. I think you are confusing [noexcept specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) and [noexcept operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept). We are talking about the first only.

Comment: Yes you are right. I mixed them up. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: Note to reviewers: [wrong answers are not very low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality). This should be reviewed as "Looks OK". (If you think that the answer is incorrect or otherwise unhelpful, you are, of course, free to downvote).